# Internal Hard Drive Not Visible

Tags: macos, hard-drive, desktop

I have an early 2009 MacBook running OSX 10.9.  Last week, my hard drive crashed.  I bought another and installed OS 10.9.  Everything works.  I do not, however, see the drive's icon on my desktop.  Therefore, I can't open it.

How can I fix this?  Re-booting doesn't fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

go to Finder > Preferences > General

Then select  Hard disks under "Show these items on the desktop:"